# Vehicle Theft Detected

Tags: obd-ii, mazda-3, anti-theft

Looking at engine codes on 2012 Mazda 3, there is something odd:

- P1260:00-22 theft Detected, Vehicle Immobilized
- P0138:00-28 O2 (oxygen Sensor) circuit high voltage (bank1, sensor 2)

Vehicle starts fine, drives fine, no issues with the battery. nor has it been run flat. Trying to understand what could cause the vehicle theft code, when the vehicle has clearly not been immobilized at all. Anyone ever seen something like this?

Comment: You own it since new?

Comment: Nah but owned it 8 years without issue

Comment: Perhaps a previous owner changed the instrument cluster and/or the body or engine electronics module.

Comment: Try Mazda 3 forums. Perhaps experienced owners and/oir M-techs  may have info. Here are two links;  https://www.mazda3forums.com/threads/fault-code-p1260.711034/ and https://www.mazda3revolution.com/threads/pcm-p1260-00-theft-detected-vehicle-immobilized.244786/. Service manuals are best, perhaps subscribing to alldata.diy or Mitchell data for online service manuals may help. Many manufacturer specific error codes may be retained in historical memory for dealer access with their proprietary scantool or repair shops with medium to high end scantools. Most generic readers won't decode them.

Comment: I forgot to add the code is not permanent. It is clear able.

Comment: I bought a car that activated the alarm and immobiliser a few seconds after I had driven away, because I had inadvertently pressed a button on the key fob as I was starting the car. Perhaps that was recorded as a 'theft'. (Aside: I thanked the stars that I had not just pulled out from a layby into fast traffic, and took this truly dangerous car back - within a week - for a refund).

Comment: @Weather Vane, interesting and ECU race condition. I wonder if that could have happened.

Comment: Perhaps it was because the original MB A class was designed by students, with all sorts of minor and major design flaws, which together added up to a [lemon](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/lemon). It wasn't the only reason I took it back but the last straw. Most of them ended up with car rental companies.